# Setup headers in apache2 if URL contains term

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

Using Apache 2.4.29 and looking to set some headers if the URL contains specific term (api).

Here is my attempt I set in the config file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api ENV=SIGN2
Header set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" env=SIGN2
Header set "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "*" env=SIGN2
```

I also tried:

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI ".*api.*" SIGN
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=SIGN
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*" env=SIGN
```

but that did not work.

URLs might look like:

- `https://www.example.com/api/something/another/last` This should
  set the headers
- `https://test.example.com/api/something/another/last` This should
  set the headers
- `https://prod.example.com/api/something/another/last` This should
  set the headers
- `https://www.example.com/hello/world/test` This should not.

Comment: Does it have to set the header if `api` is anywhere in the URL or just for URLs starting with `/api/`?

Comment: "did not work" - Your first version (using mod_rewrite) would have broken your server! However, your second version should have "worked", providing the immediate target is a physical directory/file - as it looks like from your example. However, you would not necessarily expect requests to an "API" to map directly to a physical file?

Comment: @MrWhite the example URLs do not point to actual directories. I will edit my question

Comment: @EsaJokinen I edit the question and added more examples. It is for URLs starting with `/api/....`

Comment: Can you confirm exactly where these directives are being used? ie. In the main server config, virtual host, `<Directory>` container or `.htaccess`? @EOhm's answer would seem to be assuming these are in a _server_ or _vhost_ context (natural to assume on ServerFault), however, the results you are seeing and the directives you posted in comments below are consistent with being in a _directory_ or `.htaccess` context?

Comment: It's not because of ServerFault that I assume that, it's because of the `set in the config file`, so if it would be on a deeper level then server or vhost conext I would expect this information to be included in the snippets or at least mentioned that they are within such element. It would of course change things if they are not directly in server (or vhost) config - or if config file means .htaccess.

Comment: These settings are under the default.config file within the `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the example URLs do not point to actual directories.

In that case the request is probably being rewritten to a front-controller that routes the API call?

When the rewriting process "loops" after the first rewrite (in a directory / `.htaccess` context), any environment variables that are set during the initial phase are prefixed with `REDIRECT_`. So, as in your example, `SIGN` is renamed `REDIRECT_SIGN`. So, it's probably this environment variable that needs to be checked, not `SIGN`.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api" SIGN
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=REDIRECT_SIGN
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*" env=REDIRECT_SIGN
```

For requests that *start* `/api`.

This may seem counter intuitive, but in a *directory* context the `SIGN` env var is set on the first phase of processing and the `Header` directive is processed late on the 2nd (or 3rd...) phase of processing.

If there are additional rewrite loops (unlikely) then this env var is further renamed to `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_SIGN` and so on.

This is not an issue if the directives are directly in the main server config or virtual host.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api ENV=SIGN2
> ```

Incidentally, this is wholly invalid and would break your server. You set environment variables using the `RewriteRule` directive as @EOhm has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SetEnvIf but for mod_rewrite I can tell You what should work (we anyway use mod_rewrite so it's fine to use it for everything it provides).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/api(/.*)?$ - [E=SIGN2:1]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=SIGN2
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*" env=SIGN2
```

RewriteCond does not offer the option to change environment from what I know (it is meant to be used as filtering and some limited preprocessing for RewriteRule).
This mechanism works. There might be some corner cases where it looks like not working and need modification, so if that does not work You should state what You get instead of the expected.

Also, at least with Apache 2.2 I'm sure, there is a documentation bug. You need to set the variable to an explicit value (like `1` in my example) if You user Mod in order to mod_header Header directive to recognise it (thought mod_rewrite states it sets the variable, even when no value supplied, and Header states it just checks for the variable is set - it took me quite some time to find out why such cinstruct did not work...).

Comment: Thanks @EOhm but that did not work for me. I am using Apache 2.4.29. Visiting a url like `https://www.example.com/api/something/another/last` did not return a response with the header set in env=SIGN2

Comment: I know that syntax works on both 2.2 and 2.4 (I did not thest with that specific URI and headers but I don't think the header makes a difference).  So what if You just remove the env=SIGN2 part of the Header set statements (or add one more line with a dummy header i.e. plain `Header set X-Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` directly above, below or between current lines). Also: is the response a 2xx success response? Otherwise You need to specify always condition to the header statement. Or may it be a different vhost or some additional URL rewriting is in place that causes the URL matching fail?

Comment: The request is GET and with your suggestion I do get a 200 response but only OPTION not GET. When I remove the `env=SIGN2` I get the 200 GET response.

Comment: I sadly cannot understand Your sentence. `The request is GET and with your suggestion I do get a 200 response but only OPTION not GET.`. So You mean that You get a 200 Repsonse if You do OPTIONS request and a non-200 if You do GET request?  Also Your 2nd sentence. It was not about getting a 200 response but getting the headers back. So are they inlcuded if You remove the env=SIGN2? Are there more RewriteRules or RewriteConditions in effect for same vhost?

Comment: I do have more rewrite below it `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: So when I visit the url on the browser it is a GET request I get a 200 Response. When I remove the env=SIGN2 I get the headers back. When I set the headers with env=SIGN2 I do not get the headers back

Comment: Hmm that basicaly should mean eigther the RewriteRule is not reached or it does not find the leading `/api` in requested ressource.  You could try to make an additional rewrite in same rule to see if that kicks in.  Or post a bigger picture of Your httpd config.

Comment: Or even simpler, maybe You did not load the mod_env? On some operating systems / setup it is not enabled(loaded) by default.

Comment: It works when I change the RewritRule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ - [E=SIGN2:1]`

Comment: so at that place the the requested ressource is neighther /api nor begins with /api/.. so just figure out why and what is there to fix that regex. I would need a bug picture of the config to tell You and possibly some request details (exact request and response headers, incl. possible redirects etc..)

Comment: @MrWhite answer. His answer made it work.